# OpenGL Transformation doesn't work on z-axis as expected

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, coordinate-transformation

I am writing a game engine and have trouble with the translation on the z-axis.
When I translate more than 1 unit on the z-axis the object dissappears. Values less than 1 have no effect on the object it stays in the same position.
All other transformations seem to work fine.

Part of mainloop:

```
while (unprocessedTime > frameTime) {
    rendering = true;

    unprocessedTime -= frameTime;

    if (window.isClosed()) {
        stop();
    }

    Time::setDelta(frameTime);
    game.update();

    if (frameCounter >= Time::SECOND) {
        std::cout << fps << std::endl;
        fps = 0;
        frameCounter = 0;
    }

}

if (rendering) {
    render();
    fps++;
}
```

Render method:

```
void MainController::render() {
    window.clear();
    game.render();
    window.update();
}
```

Game update and render methods:

```
void Game::update() {
    tmp += Time::getDelta();
    float sinTemp = sin(tmp);
    transform.setPos(glm::vec3(0, 0, sinTemp));
}

void Game::render() {
    shader.bind();
    shader.setUniform("transform", transform.getTransformation());
    mesh.draw();
}
```

Shader setUniform method:

```
void Shader::setUniform(std::string uniformName, glm::mat4 value) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[uniformName], 1, GL_FALSE, &value[0][0]);
}
```

Transform getTransformation method:

```
inline glm::mat4 getTransformation() const {
    glm::mat4 posMat = glm::translate(pos);
    glm::mat4 rotXMat = glm::rotate(rot.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
    glm::mat4 rotYMat = glm::rotate(rot.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    glm::mat4 rotZMat = glm::rotate(rot.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    glm::mat4 scaleMat = glm::scale(scale);

    glm::mat4 rotMat = rotZMat * rotYMat * rotXMat;

    return posMat * rotMat * scaleMat;
}
```

edit vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main() {
    color = vec4(clamp(position, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Which direction are you translating in? Change the sign and see what happens. One dir points towards the camera (ie, the object will be behind you), the other away from the camera.

Comment: Worse than that, by convention the positive z points towards you, as per the graph-paper analogy that also has the origin in the bottom left, whereas most people now seem to consider it more natural that a larger z value should mean further away, not further in front of the virtual screen (i.e. closer to you, or behind you).

Comment: Yes, I think that's due to DirectX and OpenGL having opposing conventions.

Comment: I tried bot directions (negative and positive) same result

Comment: You need a projection matrix (orthographic or perspective). See the links in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a projection matrix. Here's a good [explanation](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix) of what it is, and here's a [tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) on how to construct one.

Basically, a projection matrix divides x and y by z, so that objects further away appear smaller. It also scales z, so that the furthest distance you can see (the far clipping plane) is equivalent to -1, and the closest distance you can see is equivalent to 1. Everything outside the cube (-1,-1,-1), (1, 1, 1) is not drawn.

Without a projection matrix, your objects will not show depth properly, and will require some seemingly random scale in order to be visible on screen.